# In IntelliJ how do I Update Project (ctrl+T) with modules from different SVN locations

Tags: intellij-idea

I have an IntelliJ project made up of many modules (15+), where each module comes from their own (distinct) SVN location. The project is not stored in SVN, just each module.

Project Foo (not in SVN)

- Module 1 http://svn.example.com/projects/module1/trunk
- Module 2 http://svn.example.com/projects/module2/branches/bar
- Module 3 http://svn.example.com/projects/module3/tag/2012-11-01

I would like to be able to do Update Project (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>). Normally (when the entire project is stored in the same VCS location) I can do this once. But with each module stored in a different VCS location I have to update each module manually.

Is there a way that I can update all modules with a single command?

I am using IntelliJ 11. (But nothing is stopping me from upgrading to 12 if needed.)

Answer (score -2):

In Project settings -> Version Control, you can add all your vcs Directory with vcs type.

Comment: Thanks @XiujunMa but if I go to Project settings -> Version Control I can already see the three directories (Module 1, Module 2 and Module 3) listed and set to Subversion as the VCS.

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot with your VCS directory mappings?